# C++11 range-based for exceptional error

Tags: c++, c++11

I have been trying to learn The Revised C++11 and while trying a program with
`auto` and `nullptr` using range-based `for`, I have a error: the program exits after
accepting the first element of the array.

```
#include<iostream>

auto *Alloc(auto *p, int size) {
    if (p != nullptr)
        delete[]p;

    p = new auto[size];
    return p;
}

int main() {
    int *P = nullptr;
    Alloc(P, 5);

    for (auto &X : P)
        std::cin >> X;

    for (auto X : P)
        std::cout << X;

    std::cin.ignore(5);

    delete[]P;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: you are passing a pointer by value (besides the fact that your code shouldn't compile.)

Comment: In C++, deleting nullptr has no effect, so checking for nullptr before deleing is useless.

Comment: You're misusing `auto`. It's not meant as a replacement of templates and cannot be used like that. How can you say "the program exits after accepting the first element" if it never has been successfully compiled? what kind of crazy compiler do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P is not an array. It is defined as pointer.P

```
int *P=nullptr;
```

Pointers have no information about whether they point a separate single object or the first object of a sequence. There are no functions `begin()` and `end()` for pointers that are implicitly used in the range based for statement.

Take into account that instead of

```
int *P = nullptr;
Alloc(P, 5);
```

you have to write

```
int *P = nullptr;
P = Alloc(P, 5);
```

otherwise P will still be equal to nullptr.